# How to find Z score of each value in row of Table?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a table in R, how do I make a value in the row that is greater or equal to a certain number a 1 and the rest of the values a 0. For example, if my special number was 4, then every value that is 4 and above 4 in my table would be 1, and the rest would be zero. For example then this table:

```
         a  b  c  d  e 
Bill     1  2  3  4  5
Susan    4  1  5  4  2
Malcolm  4  5  6  2  1 
Reese    0  0  2  3  8

        Would Turn Into
         a  b  c  d  e 
Bill     0  0  0  1  1
Susan    1  0  1  1  0
Malcolm  1  1  1  0  0 
Reese    0  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can create a logical matrix of `TRUE/FALSE` and convert to binary format by using `+`

```
   +(df1>=4)
   #        a b c d e
   #Bill    0 0 0 1 1
   #Susan   1 0 1 1 0
   #Malcolm 1 1 1 0 0
   #Reese   0 0 0 0 1
```

Just to be clear, when we do the `>=`, it creates a logical matrix of `TRUE/FALSE`

```
   df1 >=4
   #            a     b     c     d     e
   #Bill    FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
   #Susan    TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
   #Malcolm  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
   #Reese   FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

But, the OP wanted this to be convert it to `1/0`.  There are many ways to do this by coercing TRUE/FALSE to binary form.  One option is

```
  (df1>=4) + 0L
```

Or

```
  (df1>=4)*1L
```

Or simply putting a `+` will do the coercion

```
  +(df1>=4)
```

According to `?TRUE`

> Logical vectors are coerced to integer vectors in contexts where a
>        numerical value is required, with ‘TRUE’ being mapped to ‘1L’,
>        ‘FALSE’ to ‘0L’ and ‘NA’ to ‘NA_integer_’.

We could also wrap with `as.integer`, but the output will be a vector

```
 as.integer(df1>=4)
 #[1] 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

If we assign the output back to the original dataset, we can change that dataset and keep its structure

```
  df1[] <- as.integer(df1>=4)
  df1
  #        a b c d e
  #Bill    0 0 0 1 1
  #Susan   1 0 1 1 0  
  #Malcolm 1 1 1 0 0
  #Reese   0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: wha the hell is going on here? could you please add a little explanation... I really do not understand how you did that magic!

Comment: @SabDeM I added some description.  Hope it helps.

Comment: yes now it is clear... I am wonder why the creator of R wanted to make the `+` function a sort of transformers. It is impossible to guess that behavior of `+`.

Comment: @SabDeM I don't know the reason behind it.